# Glow effect in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Can glow effects be applied on text inside UITextView?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. You might be able to use a CSS-styled (using the `text-shadow` property) `<textarea>` in a `UIWebView`, though.

Comment: You can indeed add a glow as of iOS6. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to add a red glow to a UITextView. Requires iOS 6+. Adjust parameters to taste:

```
NSShadow *shadow         = [NSShadow new];
shadow.shadowBlurRadius  = 5;
shadow.shadowColor       = [UIColor redColor];
shadow.shadowOffset      = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSShadowAttributeName:shadow};

textView.attributedText  = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                        initWithString:title
                                            attributes:attributes];
```